# как получить данные с php через fetch api

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, api, fetch

У меня есть два файла getPosts.php и main.js

Я хочу c js файла отправить запрос на php и получить массив.

Я на файле getPosts.php ->
получил данные с базы данных и сохранил его в массив

И как с помощью fetch api js получить этот массив

Файл php =>

```
include 'database.php';

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `posts`';

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$posts = [];

$i = 0;

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $posts[$i][0] = $row['title'];
    $posts[$i][1] = $row['_text'];

    $i++;
}

// for ($i = 0; $i < count($posts); $i++) {
//     for ($j = 0; $j < count($posts[$i]); $j++) {
//         echo $i.' '.$j.'-массив'. '='. $posts[$i][$j];
//         echo '<br>';
//     }
// }

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Файл js у меня пустой, туда надо написать запрос

Как это реализовать? Если так делать не правильно подскажите, напишите свой мнения

Пока учусь писать запросы.

Answer (score 0):

Пример получения массива с сервера с помощью fetch api

```
let url = 'https://{ссылка}/getPosts.php';
let response = await fetch(url);
// Получаем массив
let commits = await response.json();
console.log(commits[0]);
```

fetch возвращает промис, поэтому можно получить результат и так

```
fetch('https://{ссылка}/getPosts.php')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(commits => console.log(commits[0]))
```

Для более подробной информации можете прочитать урок на сайте https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch